# How wrap list within the frame boundaries in python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, radiobuttonlist

[image: How to make sure my radio button list is within the frame]

I am trying to list all the categories placed left of each other. The problem I am facing is that it is going beyond the frame boundaries and not coming down to the new line. Any work around for this ?

```
   var = IntVar()
   for i in xrange(len(ultraCategories)):
      i =  Radiobutton(midFrame,text=ultraCategories[i],variable=var,value=i,command=sel)
      i.pack(side = LEFT)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the .grid layout manager for Tkinter you can specify the row and column of where you would like to place each item. There is no built in function to split items in to a new row.

[Tkinter Grid Layout](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)